# Library/package contains multiple modules, those modules contains many classes (methods) / functions. How to import them in the following case?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, python-import

The following code works-

```
import sklearn.linear_model
clf= sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV()
```

The following code does not work-

```
import sklearn
clf= sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV()
```

whereas in case of Numpy, the following also works

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint()
```

Why is that? Please elaborate.

Comment: For me, both worked

Comment: @bigbounty did you tried this on spyder or any installed IDE?

Comment: I used `ipython`